# How to convert VARCHAR into a date format?

Tags: php, mysql, function, datetime, time

There is a table column with the date format `varchar` and `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Now I would like to display the date as a string. At the moment there is the date and even the time. I have no clue how to solve this.

I already tried converting by using `strtotime()`:

```
$doa = $data['date']
...
$time = strtotime( $doa );
$date_format = date( 'd.m.y', $time );
```

what displays a wrong date `01.01.70`.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

...and here is how it will be stored in the db:

```
$timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$timestamp = time();
$db_date = date("d.m.Y - H:i:ss", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Did you except 0.0.00? (Well, the begining of the unix age is at the 1th January 1970.) Or did you except another format of the string?

Comment: [**Mysql STR_TO_DATE(col,format)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @subhanker dd.mm.year

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I mean exact output like *29.11.2013* ,Actually date starts from 01.01.1970 so what is exact expected output.

Comment: what does $time contain? i think i should contain a Unix timestamp, but accordingly to your output. Thats not the case.

Comment: Its a specific date when a user has registerd. So it would be something like 24.04.2012 etc. The format should be seperated by points. In the db it is saved like that but with the damn time.

Comment: I updated the question how the time gets stored into the db.

Comment: You know that storing date/time data as VARCHAR is bad right? There are DATE, TIME, and DATETIME types for a reason.

Comment: ..and why should that be bad?

Answer (score 0):

When you're saving your date to the database, you're saving it as "varchar", so it's a string. Most probably your format is created like this before inserting the code into the database:

```
$date_format = date('Y-m-d H-i-s', $time);
```

This will convert a date to your "0000-00-00 00:00:00" format. I don't know about "months" and "days" at your format, so you might switch "m-d" pair in the above date() arguments.

Then you're pulling the data from the database, and in fact your have the correct code. You pull data in "0000-00-00 00:00:00" format, then convert it to Unix time (strtotime) and then format it using date() function. You just need to keep in mind that Unix time started at the 1th of January, 1970. This is why you're getting "01.01.70" from your code when applying zeros as a date string.

A short conclusion to all this: if you have any actual date (not all zeros) stored in your database, then all should be really fine.

Honestly speaking, [PHP Date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) has all clear details on date formatting, you can easily grab the idea.

Of course i can be mistaken and you have some more details, i just can't yet post to comments, a newbie here.